# Does Using Query Parameters For Routing/Navigation Have Any Bad Side Effects?

Tags: php, web, routes, svelte, slim

I was tasked with working on navigation for a website that uses PHP, Slim, and Svelte for backend, routing, and UI respectively.

I'm facing a problem now where client-side routing isn't possible because of the fact that Svelte components are mapped to different Slim routes for example:

1. `/store`
2. `/account`
3. `/orders`

I thought about using query parameters for inter-component routing (i.e. Navigating between component routes) for example:

1. `/store?route=tools`
2. `/account?route=reset`
3. `/orders?route=recent`

I wanted to know:

1. Are there any downsides to this approach?
2. Does it in any way cause problems to the user/browser?
3. Does it have any security-related issues?

EDIT:

In order to make the question clearer here is an example of what I'm trying to achieve:

Assume I have the following Slim routes:

- `/home`
- `/cart`
- `/orders`
- `/account`

Each of the previous routes points to a different Svelte component and each component should be able to render different things depending on the route's URL for example:

- `/cart` can have the subroute `/cart/checkout`. This makes the `Cart` component render the checkout controls instead of the normal cart ones.
- `/orders` can have the subroute `/orders/recent` which renders the recent order controls instead of normal ones.
- etc...

The problem is I can't achieve this because I can't extract the `/orders/[subroute_name]` for instance from inside components as they're themselves subroutes.

Comment: Can you explain more what you mean by "routing" here?  A routing is a typically a many to one mapping between URLs and the code that handles them.  Would `/orders?route=recent` be a URL that shows a list of recent orders?  If so, why would you use `route=` in the URL rather than something more meaningful like `sort=recent`?

Comment: `/orders?route=recent` would be a URL that navigates the `Orders` component to the `RecentOrders` page that displays a list of recent orders.

Comment: I'd expect `/orders` to show that content, not sure why the query string would be needed in that case.

Comment: `/orders` in this case isn't a "normal" route, it points to a page that contains a component that can render different things depending on the route. It should be `/orders/recent` and not `/orders?route=recent`.

Comment: `/orders/recent` is simpler, comparatively user-friendly, and not tied to any particular technology (such as the specific routing method you are using).  So yes, it is a better URL.

Comment: I know but I ***can't*** use it since the components themselves are subroutes and I can't extract subroute names from subroutes (for example: `/orders/[subroute_name]`.

Comment: You don't give enough technical details to know for sure, but it is usually possible to make pretty much any URL work using tools like rewrite rules, custom routing rules in PHP, and custom JavaScript routing rules.  Your particular framework may have limitations which is usually a sign of a poorly designed content management system.

Answer (score 0):

The best URLs:

- Adequately describe the content
- Are short enough to be memorable and easily typed
- Don't have to change if the technology powering your site changes

Using query parameters in your URLs works and doesn't introduce huge problems, but it does make them significantly harder for users to understand.  The `?route=` in the URLs is just there for your tech stack and makes your URL usability worse.

Even simplifying your suggestions to remove `route=` would be an improvement.  `/orders?recent` is a much better URL than `/orders?route=recent`